# How to double JOIN properly in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select all `transactions` with the billing_address city in 'New York', but with the shipping_address city not in 'New York'. The problem I'm struggling with is that when looking at the `transactions` table, there's two columns (`shipping_address_id` and `billing_address_id`), where the respective id for both is stored in the`address_table` as two seperate records.

Since I need to check whether or not the shipping/billing address is 'New York' for both those columns in the `transactions` table, I'm trying to do a double join to the `address_table` in my query, though it doesn't seem to be working properly. Does anyone see where I'm going wrong here? Thanks!

```
SELECT billing.id AS billing_address, shipping.id AS shipping_address
FROM transactions AS t
LEFT JOIN address_table AS billing
ON t.billing_address_id = billing.id
AND billing.city = 'New York'
AND t.billing_address_id IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN address_table AS shipping
ON t.shipping_address_id = shipping.id
AND shipping.city != 'New York'
AND t.shipping_address_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Can you sample data and expected result. Query looks good to me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding correctly, you just need to use an `inner join`:

```
SELECT t.*,
       b.id AS billing_address, 
       s.id AS shipping_address
FROM transactions AS t
       JOIN address_table AS b ON t.billing_address_id = b.id      
       JOIN address_table AS s ON t.shipping_address_id = s.id
WHERE b.city = 'New York' AND
      s.city != 'New York'
```